# xPages execute SSJS from CSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to run SSJS from CSJS script library... This command works fine in Client Side JavaScript library:

```
var myVar = "#{javascript:getComponent('myCustomControl').getPropertyMap().property1 = 'test'}";
```

When I check custom control property1 from SSJS it shows **test**. So works fine. But I need to substitute 'test' value with some variable, like:

```
function myFunction(testID){
     var myVar = "#{javascript:getComponent('myCustomControl').getPropertyMap().property1 = '" + testID + "'}";
}
```

Now when I check customcontrol property1 property it says exactly

```
'" + testID + "'
```

so it doesn't calculate/substitute

Answer (score 4):

I created a video tutorial on how to run SSJS from Client Side JavaScript using Remote Services. It's extremely powerful and allows you to pass parameters and return various objects back to CSJS for processing.

[Click here to watch this video tutorial on NotesIn9.com](http://www.notesin9.com/2011/08/25/notesin9-033-introduction-to-remote-services-in-xpages/)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jardin.. But seems this method doesn't work to set some scope variable in RPC then read it by SSJS. Also, I was trying to set customcontrol property in RPC  getComponent("CustomControlName").getPropertyMap().propertyName = newValue   then read it in SSJS compositeData.propertyName. It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can't run SSJS from a client side JavaScript library

Comment: but this works var myVar = "#{javascript:getComponent('myCustomControl').getPropertyMap().property1 = 'test'}";        OK.. do you have an example how can I set custom control property by CSJS?

Comment: Do you have that code in a client side JavaScript library?

Comment: This doesn't work:          function myFun(par1) {
  var myVar1 = "#{javascript:getComponent('myCustomControl').getPropertyMap().property1 = '" + par1 + "'}";
 }        This does:            function myFun() {
  var myVar1 = "#{javascript:getComponent('myCustomControl').getPropertyMap().property1 = 'aaa'}";
 }

Comment: Server side javascript code you have in client javascript libraries will not be executed server side

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error.

You have the double-quotes enclosed in single quotes when setting the value.

```
'" + testID + "'
```

If you need the value of testID in quotes, use

```
'"' + testID + '"'
```

If you just need the value of testID just use

```
testID
```

Amiright?